# Detect when elements within a scrollable div are out of view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tracking, viewport

I need to find a good solution to the following problem. I see a lot of people asking about tracking if an element is in or outside of view Port for the page or browser window. I need to be able to replicate this action, but inside a DIV that scrolls, with overflow:scroll for example. Does anyone know of a good example, for this specific action?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

i had the same problem before, i have ended up with the following function.the first parameter is for the element to check, the second is to check if the element is partially in-view.it is for vertical check only, you can extend it to check for horizontal scroll.

```
function checkInView(elem,partial)
{
    var container = $(".scrollable");
    var contHeight = container.height();
    var contTop = container.scrollTop();
    var contBottom = contTop + contHeight ;

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top - container.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    var isTotal = (elemTop >= 0 && elemBottom <=contHeight);
    var isPart = ((elemTop < 0 && elemBottom > 0 ) || (elemTop > 0 && elemTop <= container.height())) && partial ;

    return  isTotal  || isPart ;
}
```

check it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b63rH/) .

Comment: Thanks. I have seen different solutions to this, and this is the clearest, cleanest method of getting it done. Thanks!

Comment: nice to hear that, i'll make a simple jquery plugin for it :)

Comment: What if the container is scrollable and it is not in view?

Answer (score 40):

Here's a pure javascript version of the accepted answer without relying on jQuery and with some fixes to the partial in view detection and support for out of view on top.

```
function checkInView(container, element, partial) {

    //Get container properties
    let cTop = container.scrollTop;
    let cBottom = cTop + container.clientHeight;

    //Get element properties
    let eTop = element.offsetTop;
    let eBottom = eTop + element.clientHeight;

    //Check if in view    
    let isTotal = (eTop >= cTop && eBottom <= cBottom);
    let isPartial = partial && (
      (eTop < cTop && eBottom > cTop) ||
      (eBottom > cBottom && eTop < cBottom)
    );

    //Return outcome
    return  (isTotal  || isPartial);
}
```

And as a bonus, this function ensures the element is in view if it's not (partial or full):

```
function ensureInView(container, element) {

    //Determine container top and bottom
    let cTop = container.scrollTop;
    let cBottom = cTop + container.clientHeight;

    //Determine element top and bottom
    let eTop = element.offsetTop;
    let eBottom = eTop + element.clientHeight;

    //Check if out of view
    if (eTop < cTop) {
      container.scrollTop -= (cTop - eTop);
    }
    else if (eBottom > cBottom) {
      container.scrollTop += (eBottom - cBottom);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your ensureInView function should add offsetTop
```let cTop = container.scrollTop + container.offsetTop```

Comment: That does not seem to work for me, it in fact breaks the function in my use case.

Comment: What is the purpose of `partial` field in `checkInView`?

Comment: That is a flag to check if the element should be partially in view or fully in view.

Comment: Now there is this `element.scrollIntoView()` function that works fine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView useful for to ensure the element is visible

Comment: While that's a nice method, I find that its lack of customisable offset makes it a bit less practical than using for example window.scrollTo()

Comment: It depends whether the container is "positioned" (has position: relative or position: absolute). If it is then you shouldn't subtract container.offsetTop, if it isn't then you should.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your element is not a direct child of the container you will need to recursively add up all elem.offsetParent.offsetTop's etc until you reach the container

Comment: That's some very constructive and useful feedback there, @FedericoSchiocchet

Comment: Plus one for checking that all answers won't work for horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 8):

Based of the best answer. Instead of just telling you if an element is partially visible or not. I added a little extra so you can pass in a percentage (0-100) that tells you if the element is more than x% visible.

```
function (container, element, partial) {
    var cTop = container.scrollTop;
    var cBottom = cTop + container.clientHeight;
    var eTop = element.offsetTop;
    var eBottom = eTop + element.clientHeight;
    var isTotal = (eTop >= cTop && eBottom <= cBottom);
    var isPartial;

    if (partial === true) {
        isPartial = (eTop < cTop && eBottom > cTop) || (eBottom > cBottom && eTop < cBottom);
    } else if(typeof partial === "number"){
        if (eTop < cTop && eBottom > cTop) {
            isPartial = ((eBottom - cTop) * 100) / element.clientHeight > partial;
        } else if (eBottom > cBottom && eTop < cBottom){ 
            isPartial = ((cBottom - eTop) * 100) / element.clientHeight > partial;
        }
    }
    return (isTotal || isPartial);
}
```

Comment: This is also jQuery-free.

Comment: Yes I like to avoid jQuery

Comment: Out of all the other ones, only this one seems to work properly for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to make this work by making a small change to the pure javascript version posted

```
function checkInView(container, element, partial) {

    //Get container properties
    let cTop = container.scrollTop;
    let cBottom = cTop + container.clientHeight;

    //Get element properties
    let eTop = element.offsetTop - container.offsetTop; // change here
    let eBottom = eTop + element.clientHeight;

    //Check if in view    
    let isTotal = (eTop >= cTop && eBottom <= cBottom);
    let isPartial = partial && (
      (eTop < cTop && eBottom > cTop) ||
      (eBottom > cBottom && eTop < cBottom)
    );

    //Return outcome
    return  (isTotal  || isPartial);
  }
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, if you want the height of your scrollcontainer to be variable. Here's a stackblitz: https://scroll-detection-poc.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2):

Played around with it for my purposes. Here is my solution (vanilla)

Menu is the container, el is the active element.

```
const isVisible = (menu, el) => {
      const menuHeight = menu.offsetHeight;
      const menuScrollOffset = menu.scrollTop;
    
      const elemTop = el.offsetTop - menu.offsetTop;
      const elemBottom = elemTop + el.offsetHeight;
      return (elemTop >= menuScrollOffset &&
     elemBottom <= menuScrollOffset + menuHeight);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the relatively new [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) (which has been supported in major browsers since 2019: https://caniuse.com/intersectionobserver).

This handles almost all edge cases I've seen for this question. (Off hand the only edge case it doesn't catch is when an absolutely positioned element is obscuring the scrolling elements.)

```js
async function isElementInScrollView(element) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            (entries, observerItself) => {
                observerItself.disconnect();
                resolve(entries[0].intersectionRatio === 1);
            }
        );
        observer.observe(element);
    });
}
```

usage:

```js
const isInView = await isElementInScrollView(document.querySelector('#my-element'));
```

You can modify the `intersectionRatio === 1` part of the function implementation to change how "in view" the element must be in order for this function to return `true`. (`intersectionRatio` is a value between `0.0` and `1.0`.) See `intersectionRatio` docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/intersectionRatio

Here's an example:

```js
async function isElementInScrollView(element) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observerItself) => {
      observerItself.disconnect();
      resolve(entries[0].intersectionRatio === 1);
    });
    observer.observe(element);
  });
}

async function detect() {
  const allChildren = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".child"));

  const results = await Promise.all(
    allChildren.map(async(child) => {
      return await isElementInScrollView(child);
    })
  );

  printResults(results);
}

function printResults(results) {
  document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = results.join('<br>')
}

detect();
```

```css
.restricted {
  padding: 32px;
  padding-right: 64px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
}

.child {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.results {
  display: inline-block;
}

body>* {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="restricted">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>

<button onclick="detect()">Detect</button>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: This is the best solution in the current year. However it could be required to specify a root object in the constructor of the IntersectionObserver if you want to check the visibility in relation to a specific scroll container.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure javascript solution.

```
function elementIsVisible(element, container, partial) {
    var contHeight = container.offsetHeight,
    elemTop = offset(element).top - offset(container).top,
    elemBottom = elemTop + element.offsetHeight;
    return (elemTop >= 0 && elemBottom <= contHeight) || 
    (partial && ((elemTop < 0 && elemBottom > 0 ) || (elemTop > 0 && elemTop <= contHeight)))
}

// checks window
function isWindow( obj ) {
    return obj != null && obj === obj.window;
}

// returns corresponding window
function getWindow( elem ) {
    return isWindow( elem ) ? elem : elem.nodeType === 9 && elem.defaultView;
}

// taken from jquery
// @returns {{top: number, left: number}} 
function offset( elem ) {

    var docElem, win,
        box = { top: 0, left: 0 },
        doc = elem && elem.ownerDocument;

    docElem = doc.documentElement;

    if ( typeof elem.getBoundingClientRect !== typeof undefined ) {
        box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
    win = getWindow( doc );
    return {
        top: box.top + win.pageYOffset - docElem.clientTop,
        left: box.left + win.pageXOffset - docElem.clientLeft
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a jquery plugin with the last answer:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.reallyVisible = function(opt) {

        var options = $.extend({
            cssChanges:[
                { name : 'visibility', states : ['hidden','visible'] }
            ],
            childrenClass:'mentioners2',
            partialview : true
        }, opt);

        var container = $(this);
        var contHeight;
        var contTop;
        var contBottom;
        var _this = this;
        var _children;

        this.checkInView = function(elem,partial){

            var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top - container.offset().top;
            var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

            var isTotal = (elemTop >= 0 && elemBottom <=contHeight);
            var isPart = ((elemTop < 0 && elemBottom > 0 ) || (elemTop > 0 && elemTop <= container.height())) && partial ;

            return  isTotal  || isPart ;
        }

        this.bind('restoreProperties',function(){
            $.each(_children,function(i,elem){
                $.each(options.cssChanges,function(i,_property){
                    $(elem).css(_property.name,_property.states[1]);        
                });
            });
            _children = null;
        });

        return this.each(function(){
            contHeight = container.height();
            contTop = container.scrollTop();
            contBottom = contTop + contHeight ;

            _children = container.children("."+options.childrenClass);

            $.each(_children,function(i,elem){
                var res = _this.checkInView(elem,options.partialview);
                if(  !res ){
                    $.each(options.cssChanges,function(i,_property){
                        $(elem).css(_property.name,_property.states[0]);        
                    });
                }
            });

        }); 
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + window.innerHeight;
    var el = $(elem);
    var elemTop = el.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + el.height();
    var elemDisplayNotNone = el.css("display") !== "none";

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop) && elemDisplayNotNone);
}
```

eg:

```
isScrolledIntoView('#button')
```