# Is there an Elm equivalent of jQuery.offset?

Tags: jquery, html, offset, elm

If I want how far my element is from the top of the screen in Elm, how do I do that?

In context, I'm trying to figure out how to tell if an element is out of view in Elm, and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308037/detect-when-elements-within-a-scrollable-div-are-out-of-view), that's the first ingredient I would need to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In Elm 0.19, [`Browser.Dom.getElement`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#getElement) will return (a task that returns) an [`Element`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#Element) record containing all the info you need.  Then you can do:

```
distFromTop : Element -> Int
distFromTop elementInfo =
    elmentInfo.element.y - elementInfo.viewport.y
```

(Note that `distFromTop` may return a negative number if the viewport is currently showing a part of the page *below* your element.)

You can see a full example of the `Task` machinery you'll need to put around this in the [`getImgPosition` function](https://github.com/jerith666/elbum/blob/dev/src/client/AlbumPage.elm#L229) in my Elbum project.

Comment: This answer is wrong. getElement returns a task, not a record.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to the y function in the [Dom library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/1.1.1/Dom-Scroll#y). Note that this sort of function is not pure (the distance down can vary) so you need to use a Task to work with it. That adds a bit of cognitive overhead for the developer, but of course gives you the other certainties that Elm offers instead.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use this to get the distance to the top of the document body rather than the top of the parent element?