# How to determine when a child iframe element is within the visible area of a scrolling div?

Tags: javascript, iframe, load, delay, onscroll

I have a scrolling div that may or may not contain one or more iframes who's contents should only be loaded when the iframe is either partly/fully visible between the parent div's scroll area's top and bottom.  However, when there are iframes in the div and when I inspect my web-page in Chrome, I see that the iframe's offsetTop values don't change as the parent div's scroll-bar is scrolled upward or downward.  Also, I see that the offsetParent of the iframes references the body element rather than the scrolling div that actually contains the iframes.

Here is a simple web-page that shows the basic div and nested iframe structure that I'm talking about:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- Scrolling div -->
    <div id="scroller" style="height:316px; width: 322px; overflow-y:scroll;">
      <!-- 5 iframes that each contain an img tag that is ignored -->
      <iframe><img id="img" src="1.png"></iframe><br />
      <iframe><img id="img" src="2.png"></iframe><br />
      <iframe><img id="img" src="3.png"></iframe><br />
      <iframe><img id="img" src="4.png"></iframe><br />
      <iframe><img id="img" src="5.png"></iframe><br />
    </div>
    <script>
      //
      // Assign an onScroll function to the scroller div that monitors the div's
      // scrolling ...
      //

      function scrollerDivScrolling() {
        var div = scrollerDivScrolling.div;

        //
        // The following code only changes the div's background color when the
        // div's scroll-bar is scrolled: white when less-than or 50px or
        // yellow when more 50px.
        //

        if( div.scrollTop > 50 ) {
          div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
        else {
          div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }

        //
        // This is code needs to check each of the iframe's position to
        // see if the iframe is displayed partially/fully between the
        // parent div's scroll area's top and bottom, and if so then the
        // iframe's content is set to the html statement(s) that are
        // between to iframe's opening and closing tags.  If the iframe's
        // position is either completely above top of the parent div's
        // scroll area or completely below the parent div's scroll area,
        // then remove the contents.
        //

      }
      scrollerDivScrolling.div          = document.getElementById( 'scroller' );
      scrollerDivScrolling.iframes      = scrollerDivScrolling.div.getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' );
      scrollerDivScrolling.div.onscroll = scrollerDivScrolling;

      // Initialize the iframes with in the scroller div to 'show' their contents ...

      for( var i = 0, iframes = scrollerDivScrolling.iframes, l = iframes.length, iframeDoc = null; i < l; ++i ) {

        iframeDoc = iframes[ i ].contentWindow.document;
        iframeDoc.open();
        iframeDoc.write('Test' + ( i + 1 ) );
        iframeDoc.close();

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As shown in the above code, the iframes are actually loaded with "Test " followed by a number, rather than the image tag statement that is within the individual iframe tags, but this isn't an issue, as I know how to do this already.  More importantly, the scrollerDivScrolling() function that handles scrolling the div doesn't actually change the content of each iframe depending on its position relative to the parent div's scroll-area's top and bottom, because I haven't figured out which properties of each iframe I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded my search and found: [Detect when elements within a scrollable div are out of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308037/detect-when-elements-within-a-scrollable-div-are-out-of-view), which I integrated with my scrollerDivScrolling() function as follows:

```
<script>
  const UNDEFINED = undefined;

  // Assign an onScroll function to the scroller div that monitors the div's scrolling ...

  function checkInView( elem, partial ) {
    var container  = $( '.scrollable' );
    var contHeight = container.height();
    var contTop    = container.scrollTop();
    var contBottom = contTop + contHeight - 1;
    var $elem      = $( elem );

    var elemTop    = $elem.offset().top - container.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    var isTotal    = ( ( elemTop >= 0 ) && ( elemBottom <= contHeight ) );
    var isPart     = false;

    if( partial ) {
      isPart  = ( ( ( elemTop < 0 ) && ( elemBottom > 0 ) ) || ( ( elemTop > 0 ) && ( elemTop <= container.height() ) ) );
    }

    return ( isTotal || isPart );
  }

  function scrollerDivScrolling() {
    var div = scrollerDivScrolling.div;

    for( var i = 0, iframes = scrollerDivScrolling.iframes, l = iframes.length, iframeDoc = null; i < l; ++i ) {

      // If the element is in the scrollable div's visible area ...

      if( checkInView( scrollerDivScrolling.iframes[ i ], true ) ) {

        // If the element had not already been loaded ...

        if( ( iframes[ i ].loaded === UNDEFINED ) || !iframes[ i ].loaded ) {

          // Mark the element as loaded and load the element ...

          iframes[ i ].loaded = true;
          iframeDoc           = iframes[ i ].contentWindow.document;
          iframeDoc.open();
          iframeDoc.write( 'Test' + ( i + 1 ) + '&nbsp' + iframes[ i ].innerHTML );
          iframeDoc.close();

        }

      }
      else {

        // Mark the element as NOT loaded and unload the element ...

        iframes[ i ].loaded = false;
        iframeDoc           = iframes[ i ].contentWindow.document;
        iframeDoc.open();
        iframeDoc.write( '' );
        iframeDoc.close();

      }

    }

  }
  scrollerDivScrolling.div          = document.getElementById( 'scroller' );
  scrollerDivScrolling.div.onscroll = scrollerDivScrolling;
  scrollerDivScrolling.iframes      = scrollerDivScrolling.div.getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' );

  // Initialize the iframes with in the scroller div to 'show' their contents ...

  for( var i = 0, iframes = scrollerDivScrolling.iframes, l = iframes.length, iframeDoc = null; i < l; ++i ) {

    iframes[ i ].loaded = UNDEFINED;

  }

  scrollerDivScrolling();
</script>
```

For me, the checkInView(...) function shows that the first three iframe elements are 'in view'when the scroller is all the way at the top, meaning that the function returns true for the first three elements in the div, even though the scrolling div's height is only tall enough to show the first two iframe elements, but this isn't really a problem for me.

Using this technique I can 'pre-load' the iframes with the html that they will show when the scrolling div scrolls each iframe into view, and img tags contained in each iframe will normally load their images as they come into view.

For me, this helps in two ways: the initial page load doesn't need to load all of the iframes before the page can be viewed and the user can begin to scroll through the 'rows' iframes' sub-pages, and the over all amount of storage needed to contain all of the data is somewhat 'flattened' because only the page data needed for the elements that are showing is loaded and the hidden rows in the scrollable div are removed. when their contents are replaced with ''.

Here is a Pen demo showing a working sample of how this works: [Scrolling Div of delay-loading iframes](https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/KbKGKW)