# Determine how many cards are displayed on horizontal scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to work on a horizontal scroll that determines how many cards are shown in the container.

Example lets say the table below are cards

| Card 1 | Card 2 | Card 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |

The display should be 3 out of 6 and the remaining 3 cards are hidden on overflow. When I scroll to the end horizontally it should show 6 out of 6 cards. Its kind of a record count but using the scroll

I have the following code below but I don't want to use jquery and I am trying to convert the code but it does not properly retrieve the width and left measurement in javascript. Check the commented code below in the jsfiddle.

- http://jsfiddle.net/ujs2r0wd/

```
function  checkInView(elem,partial)
{
    var container = $(".scrollable");
    var contHeight = container.width();
    var contTop = container.scrollLeft();
    var contBottom = contTop + contHeight ;
 
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().left - container.offset().left;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).width();
    
    var isTotal = (elemTop >= 0 && elemBottom <=contHeight);
    var isPart = ((elemTop < 0 && elemBottom > 0 ) || (elemTop > 0 && elemTop <= container.width())) && partial ;
    
    return  isTotal  || isPart ;
}
```

Here is my attempt or try:

```
function  checkInView(elem,partial)
{
    var container = document.querySelector(".scrollable");
    const contHeight = container.width;
    const contTop = container.scrollLeft;
    const contRight = contTop + contHeight;

    //const elemTop = elem.offsetLeft - container.offsetLeft;
    console.log($(elem).offset().left);
    console.log($(elem).offsetLeft);
    var elemTop = elem.offset().left - container.offset().left;
    const elemBottom = elemTop + elem.width;

    const isTotal = (elemTop >= 0 && elemBottom <= contHeight);
    const isPart = ((elemTop < 0 && elemBottom > 0) || (elemTop > 0 && elemTop <= container.width)) && partial;
    
    return  isTotal  || isPart ;
}
```

```
  function ready (){
    const getEle = document.querySelector(".scrollable");
    document.querySelector(".scrollable").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
         var result="",
       result2="";
       for (var i = 0, i >= getEle.length; i++) {
            result += " " +  checkInView(e,false);
            result2 += " " +  checkInView(e,true);
       }
       
       console.log(result);
       console.log(result2);
        });
};
```

Reference: [Detect when elements within a scrollable div are out of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308037/detect-when-elements-within-a-scrollable-div-are-out-of-view)

Could you please help me convert the code or could you show in code how I could do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Provide your attempted non-jquery code.

Comment: @vanowm Added the attempt in the question but it can be found on the jsfiddle

Comment: You are still using jquery in the attempt `$(elem)` is jquery, in fact `elem` is a jquery object, not actual element

Comment: @vanowm I did not know that. Thanks for pointing that one out. But this was the attempt and also the reason why I wanted to use purely javascript.