# How can I optimize iterating and manipulating the DOM on a huge array of elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list that ranges from 20,000 up to 50,000 of filenames.

I show them all in a list constrained by max width and height.

Then present an input so the user can filter elements by searching a string.

With a low number of items it works fine but with the amount of items I have it's very inefficient and I might run into OOM errors or it might take minutes to update.

I want prefiltering before the initial print of filenames to be my last resort so I was wondering if there's any way to make this faster or more efficient.

At first I thought that it was a problem of having too many CSS transitions so I made it so the transitions only applied to the elements which were visible in the scrollable UL, if it helped any it's not noticeable with +20K elements.

Here's html/css/js to test.

```js
const fileList = document.getElementById('file_list');
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search_input');
const numFilesInput = document.getElementById('num_files_input');
const regenerateButton = document.getElementById('regenerate_button');

// Configure the number of fake files to retrieve
let numFiles = parseInt(numFilesInput.value); // Initial value

// Generate fake files
let files = generateFakeFiles(numFiles);

// Display all files initially
displayFiles(files);

// Add event listener for search input
searchInput.addEventListener('input', handleSearch);

// Add event listener for regenerate button
regenerateButton.addEventListener('click', regenerateFiles);

// Function to generate fake files
function generateFakeFiles(num) {
  const files = [];
  const extensions = ['.txt', '.doc', '.pdf', '.jpg', '.png']; // Add more extensions if desired

  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    const fileName = `file${i}${extensions[Math.floor(Math.random() * extensions.length)]}`;
    files.push(fileName);
  }

  return files;
}

// Function to regenerate files
function regenerateFiles() {
  numFiles = parseInt(numFilesInput.value);
  files = generateFakeFiles(numFiles);
  displayFiles(files);
}


// Function to display files
function displayFiles(files) {
  fileList.innerHTML = '';
  files.forEach(file => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = file;
  li.addEventListener("transitionend", transition_ended);
    fileList.appendChild(li);
  });
}

// Function to handle search
function handleSearch() {
  const searchString = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
  console.log("Searching for '"+searchString+"'");
  console.log(fileList);
  console.log(fileList.parentNode);
  let fileListClone = fileList.cloneNode(true);
  let filesClones = fileListClone.querySelectorAll('li');
  let dFrag  = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < filesClones.length; i++) {
    const file = filesClones[i];
    const fileName = file.textContent.toLowerCase();
    if (fileName.includes(searchString)) {
      // Add a `flash_green` class to the file list item to highlight it if it matches the search string.
      if (file.className == "hidden") {
        file.className = "flash_green";
      }
    } else {
      // Add a `flash_red` class to the file list item to indicate that it doesn't match the search string.
      if (file.className != "hidden") {
        file.className = "flash_red";
      }
    }
  }
  dFrag.appendChild(fileListClone);
  fileList.parentNode.replaceChild(dFrag, fileList);
}

function transition_ended(event) {
  // Get the target element
  let element = event.target;

  if (element !== this) {
    return;
  }

  // Log the element and its current class name
  console.log(
    `Transition ended for ${element.tagName}#${element.id}, at this point className is ${element.className}`
  );

  // If the element's class name is "flash_red" or "collapsed", hide it and uncheck its checkbox
  if (element.className == "flash_red" || element.className == "collapsed") {
    element.className = "hidden";
    element.checked = false;
  }

  // If the element's class name is "flash_green" or "flash_red", remove the flash class
  if (element.className == "flash_green" || element.className == "flash_red") {
    element.className = "";
  }
}
```

```css
ul#file_list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    overflow: scroll;
    max-width: 100rem;
    max-height: 50rem;
}

#file_list li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 33%;
}
#file_list li.flash_red {
  animation: flash_red 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes flash_red {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

#file_list li.flash_green {
  animation: flash_green 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  opacity: 100;
}

@keyframes flash_green {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h4>File List</h4>
    <input id="num_files_input" type="number" value="100" min="1" />
    <button id="regenerate_button">Regenerate</button>
    <br>
    <input id="search_input" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
    <ul id="file_list"></ul>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Updated the snippet above with the latest version I have

I've been following this, [Executing multiple DOM updates with JavaScript efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039667/executing-multiple-dom-updates-with-javascript-efficiently#comment120097333_37039667)
`// Update the vDOM and access DOM just once by rAF`
seems to work fine and fast, however when I search for the second character it seems like fileList has lost it's parentNode.

Also the transition is still not being applied. Once I drop the new HTML the elements with the class `flash_red` start at opacity 0 and the transition ended event is not fired or is not neing listened to.

Comment: how do you fetch file names? Can you use pagination when you are making the request?

Comment: Pagination is the common solution. Create on the server side a route that can respond to a GET request with params like limit, page, filter - with a subset of the matching list.

Comment: Touching the DOM is relatively slow and expensive compared to manipulating strings and arrays.   Keep an array of your filenames to search against instead of reading it from the DOM; build your results HTML as a string and drop it into the DOM only when it's complete.

Comment: Those frequent `getBoundingClientRect` calls are likely also rather costly. Not sure what the point of those is supposed to be to begin with, because the selection I am getting does not appear to be limited to how much fits into the viewport anyway?

Comment: I wanted to hide or show elements without having them go through the `flash_red` or `flash_green` transitions if they're not visible. I was trying to maintain the red and green flashes so the user sees that there are elements being filtered in and out. That's why I wanted to have pagination/server side filtering as a last resort.

Comment: In that case what I'd do is build the results string, drop it into the DOM, and then add the transitions to the elements within the viewport.    (which can be relatively quick, because you can bail out of the loop the first time you hit one that's out of view.)

Comment: Am I not doing that? On the loop with `const isVisible = isElementVisible(file, fileList);`. I also tried this function which doesn't use boundingclientrect https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253390/5640517 but it's seems it's still slow. Also I don't think I can exit early, I still have to update the classes to add or remove `hidden`, and if the user has scrolled it won't be true that the first out of view means the rest is also out of view.

Comment: Maybe I could do server side filtering and fake the red and green flashes, like the magic trick in which you pick a card from a set of J,  and K, then the next time you see the deck it's gone, but when you look closely you see that the other cards are all different from the first set.

Comment: " I still have to update the classes to add or remove hidden". No, because you'd be building the new HTML string anew and dropping it into the DOM once, with all the correct classes already in place.  Your code is slow because it's touching the DOM at every possible opportunity.  Don't `appendChild` repeatedly within a loop; build up a new HTML string and drop it into the DOM after the loop is completed. It'll be much, much, much faster.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing multiple DOM updates with JavaScript efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039667/executing-multiple-dom-updates-with-javascript-efficiently)

Comment: @DanielBeck I think I've tried what you're suggesting. Opened the snippet locally, created 100 elements, copied and pasted to have 50K elements, then added to the first 10 the class `flash_red` the elements dissappear but leave the empty space. Probably because they're missing the `transition_ended` event listener. Updated the main post. Thank you.

Comment: I've been following this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039667/executing-multiple-dom-updates-with-javascript-efficiently#comment120097333_37039667 it seems to work fine and fast, however when I search for the second character it seems like fileList has lost it's parentNode.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot paginate, at least

Delegate

```
const fileList = document.getElementById('file_list');
fileList.addEventListener("transitionend", transition_ended);
```

and make only ONE DOM update

```
function displayFiles(files) {
  fileList.innerHTML = files.map(file => `<li>${file}</li>`).join("")
}
```

Also play with toggle.

```
    file.classList.toggle("flash_green",isVisible && fileName.includes(searchString));
    file.classList.toggle("flash_red",isVisible && !fileName.includes(searchString));
    file.classList.toggle("hidden",!isVisible);
```

The example does not get the toggle correct right now but it is worth fixing

```js
const fileList = document.getElementById('file_list');
fileList.addEventListener("transitionend", transition_ended);
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search_input');
const numFilesInput = document.getElementById('num_files_input');
const regenerateButton = document.getElementById('regenerate_button');

// Configure the number of fake files to retrieve
let numFiles = parseInt(numFilesInput.value); // Initial value

// Generate fake files
let files = generateFakeFiles(numFiles);

// Display all files initially
displayFiles(files);

// Add event listener for search input
searchInput.addEventListener('input', handleSearch);

// Add event listener for regenerate button
regenerateButton.addEventListener('click', regenerateFiles);

// Function to generate fake files
function generateFakeFiles(num) {
  const files = [];
  const extensions = ['.txt', '.doc', '.pdf', '.jpg', '.png']; // Add more extensions if desired
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    const fileName = `file${i}${extensions[Math.floor(Math.random() * extensions.length)]}`;
    files.push(fileName);
  }
  return files;
}

// Function to regenerate files
function regenerateFiles() {
  numFiles = parseInt(numFilesInput.value);
  files = generateFakeFiles(numFiles);
  displayFiles(files);
}


// Function to display files
function displayFiles(files) {
  fileList.innerHTML = files.map(file => `<li>${file}</li>`).join("")
}

// Function to handle search
function handleSearch() {
  const searchString = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
    // Get all the file list items in the file list.
    const files = fileList.querySelectorAll("li");
    // Iterate over each file list item and check if its text content includes the search string.
    for (let i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const file = files[i];
        const fileName = file.textContent.toLowerCase();
        const isVisible = isElementVisible(file, fileList);
        file.classList = "";
        file.classList.toggle("flash_green",isVisible && fileName.includes(searchString));
        file.classList.toggle("flash_red",isVisible && !fileName.includes(searchString));
        file.classList.toggle("hidden",!isVisible);        
    };
}


// Function to check if an element is visible inside a container
function isElementVisible(element, container) {
    const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        elementRect.top >= containerRect.top &&
        elementRect.bottom <= containerRect.bottom &&
        elementRect.left >= containerRect.left &&
        elementRect.right <= containerRect.right
    );
}

function transition_ended(event) {
    // Get the target element
    let element = event.target.closest("li");
    if (!element)

    // Log the element and its current class name
    console.log(
        `Transition ended for ${element.tagName}#${element.id}, at this point className is ${element.className}`
    );

    // If the element's class name is "flash_red" or "collapsed", hide it and uncheck its checkbox
    if (element.className == "flash_red" || element.className == "collapsed") {
        element.className = "hidden";
        element.checked = false;
    }

    // If the element's class name is "flash_green" or "flash_red", remove the flash class
    if (element.className == "flash_green" || element.className == "flash_red") {
        element.className = "";
    }
}
```

```css
ul#file_list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    overflow: scroll;
    max-width: 100rem;
    max-height: 50rem;
}

#file_list li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 33%;
}
#file_list li.flash_red {
  animation: flash_red 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes flash_red {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

#file_list li.flash_green {
  animation: flash_green 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  opacity: 100;
}

@keyframes flash_green {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h4>File List</h4>
    <input id="num_files_input" type="number" value="100" min="1" />
    <button id="regenerate_button">Regenerate</button>
    <br>
    <input id="search_input" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
    <ul id="file_list"></ul>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it worth toggling if the element only ever has a single class? `.className =` seems more straightforward.

Comment: 1. toggle takes a boolean, 2. classList is a string. It is much more understandable and elegant